# Regex matches only some special characters

Tags: regex

I have the following regex expression, which escapes numbers and special characters. However it does not pick up characters such as !":;()<>@*%^$~#.

What it does escape is: `0-9-+&£?|\/{}`

Regex:

```
"[a-zA-Z._^%$#!~@,']+"
```

I have tried this:

`"[a-zA-Z._^!*:;()<>\"%$#!~@,']+";` But does not seem to work.

How can I expand my regex to capture these values as well?

Reason being, I do not want users to enter these characters into their first or last name on a form.

I am using this regex in javascript so it is wrap in ''

Comment: By adding them to the character class?

Comment: @MarounMaroun please see the update

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eK7yK1/2 ?

Comment: @Harry please provide examples where it fails.

Comment: The one you have posted is `[a-zA-Z._^!*:;()<>\"%$#!~@,']+` is working i think

Comment: @MarounMaroun example is in the question

Comment: @Harry Do you have those quotes on your real regex? If so, remove them.

Comment: My regex is missing the /start and close it worked by adding those as pointed out by @Shafizadeh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a character class and add everything you want to it. Something like this:

```
/[a-zA-Z._!":;()<>@*%\^$~#']+/
```

- `[]` is a character class
- `a-zA-Z._!":;()<>@*%\^$~#'` are what you mentioned in the question

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK7yK1/5)

Comment: Thanks, I had to add starting / and closing / to my regex and it does work.

Comment: Glad to help ... yes you have to use delimiter in the begin and end of your regex ..

Comment: This is working great, however how can I allow ' as some names can contain that char such as Mc'Donell.

Comment: yes, because this current regex will capture ' also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special characters in your regex string as well.

```
[a-zA-Z._^!\*\:\;\(\)\<\>\"\%\$\#\!\~\@,\']+
```

See https://regex101.com/r/eK7yK1/3

Comment: Really why did you escape them? `*`, `!` and .. doesn't have any specific mean in a character class, so you don't need to escape them. just `-` and `^` *(at the beginning of your regex)*  need to escape

Comment: Depends on the dialect you're dealing with. In some places you need to escape braces, wildcards and so on.

Comment: Yeah agreed .. *In some places you need to escape braces, wildcards and so on* .! But in this case I hardly think so ..

Comment: Right then, which is why your answer is different from mine. That's the entire point of allowing it.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using to code?

Anyway, with the few details you give, I suggest changing `"` with `/` to wrap your regex code like so: `/[a-zA-Z._^%$#!~@,']+/`.